# 25 Locker Problem - can't figure out what's wrong with my code

Tags: python, function

The following is from ProofWiki (just slightly modified the numbers):

There is a school with 25 students, and correspondingly 25 lockers, all of which start off closed. The first student opens every locker. The second student closes every other locker, starting with the second. The third student changes the state of every third locker, starting with the third. That is, if the locker is open, she closes it, and if it is closed, she opens it. This continues similarly until all 25 students have passed along the lockers. After the 25th student is done, which lockers are open and which are closed?

I already know the answer is all perfect squares, and I understand why. My goal was to try and solve the problem using code (I'm relatively new to coding), but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Here's the code:

```
for a in range (1,26):
    count_factor(a) == 0

def count_factor(a):
    for a in range (1,26):
        for b in range (1,26):
            if b%a == 0:
                count_factor(a) += 1

total = 0

for a in range (1,26):
    if count_factor(a)%2 == 1:
        total = total + 1

print (total)
```

The expected output should just be 10. However, it says there is a syntax error and that it can't assign to function call on

```
count_factor(a) += 1
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `count_factor(a)` is a call to the function `count_factor` with the parameter `a`. What do you think `count_factor(a) += 1` does?

Comment: `count_factor(a) += 1 ` is short hand for `count_factor(a)=count_factor(a) + 1` which as you can see is incorrect because you are trying to assign a value to a function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `count_factor(a) += 1` makes no sense.

When you expand the `+=` operator, that is equivalent to:

```
count_factor(a) = count_factor(a) + 1
```

You're assigning *to* a function, which is meaningless.

Comment: `<-` Assigning to a function *return* which is meaningless.